# How to pass HiveContext as an argument from one function to another function using spark scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have a sceneria where I need to pass `HiveContext` as an argument to another function. Below is my code and where I am stuck with issue:

```
Object Sample {
    def main(args:Array[String]){
        val fileName = "SampleFile.txt"
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("LoadToHivePart")  
        conf.set("spark.ui.port","4041")
        val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)  
        val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) 
        hc.setConf("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://127.0.0.1:9083")
        test(hc,fileName)
        sc.stop()
    }
    def test(hc:String, fileName: String){
        //code.....
    }
}
```

As per above code I am unable to pass a `HiveContext` variable "`hc`" from main to another function. Also tried with:

`def test(hc:HiveContext, fileName:String){}` 
but it is showing error for both.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: If you're using Spark 2, those shouldn't be used anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
def test(hc:HiveContext, fileName: String){
        //code.....
    }
```

**Note:** Hive Context available in `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext`

so import it using `import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan import might be missing otherwise it has to be some other error..

Comment: yeah I guess you are right as he initialized using `val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)`. :) +1